# want to generate dynamic grid id for enhancedgrid in dojo

Tags: dojo

I want to generate random grid ID for enhanced grid, as in one of the scenario when iam loading the enhanced grid page in dialog box it is showing the below error message:

```
**Error {info: "Tried to register widget with id==grid but that id is already registered", stack: (...), message: "Tried to register widget with id==grid but that id is already registered"}
```

info: "Tried to register widget with id==grid but that id is already registered"**

Is their any way to generate the id dynamically on page load. as its creating the grid while the page is loading.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something unique, then you can use dojo's UUID or any other UUID generator. If you  don't care what the ID is going to be (you can access the widget later on through some other means), then you can just leave out the ID attribute and let dojo's registry automatically create an ID.

Comment: Hi,For the same above question, i have been used dojo UUID for generating the grid ID, now we have to apply the css style to set the grid width and height. For that we will use                        #grid {
    width: 65em;
    height: 15em;
 } For #grid i have to replace "grid" with dynamically genrated grid id to apply the style. How can  i do that.

Comment: You can easily give it a class and apply the css by class instead. Using: .grid { width: 65em; height: 15em;}

Comment: yes but i need to give the dynamic name for "grid" which i am generating through dojo UUID as suggested above.

Comment: A class is different than an id. When you declare your enhanced grid, you can do something like:
new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
                        id: uuid.generateRandomUuid(),
                        "class":"grid",
                        store: mystore,

Comment: Thankyou Richard, but thats not working. I have modified my code as below:   var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
                     id: gridId,
                     "class":"grid",
                     store: mystore,
                     structure: layout,
                     autoWidth:true,
                  ...}                                                         /*Grid need a explicit width/height by default*/
 .grid {
    width: 65em;
    height: 15em;
 } but when i see the ouput the class style is not applied for grid.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code? I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Its difficult to create as it might work if i place the exact code, but in my application iam calling this enhanced grid on click of a column in another enhanced grid and this output should be shown on dialog box.As their are many dependencies i cannot create fiddle.sorry.